# How to get largest and smallest element in 2d array in java column wise I have got output for row wise

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

```
public class colum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] data = { 
                { 3,  2,    5,-45 }, 
                { 1,  4,    4, -8 }, 
                { 9,  6, -100,  -2 },
                {-10, 3,    1,  -2 }};


        for (int row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {

            int large = data[row][0], 
                small = data[row][0];

            for (int col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
                if (large < data[row][col]) {
                    large = data[row][col];

                }if (small > data[row][col]) {
                    small = data[row][col];
                }
            }

            System.out.println("\nlargest values:" + large);
            large = 0;
            System.out.println("smallest values:" +small);
            small = 0;

        }
    }
}
```

Output is:

largest values:5
smallest values:-45

largest values:4
smallest values:-8

largest values:9
smallest values:-100

largest values:3
smallest values:-10

Comment: so what you have is correct for each element, now compare for the values overall i.e. keep min and max declaring them outside the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch the order of the loops in order to find column wise minimum and maximum:

```
for (int col = 0; col < data[0].length; col++) { // assuming all row have same length

    int large = data[0][col], 
        small = data[0][col];

    for (int row = 1; row < data.length; row++) {
        if (large < data[row][col]) {
            large = data[row][col];

        }
        if (small > data[row][col]) {
            small = data[row][col];
        }

    }
    System.out.println("\nlargest values:" + large);
    System.out.println("smallest values:" +small);
}
```

Output:

```
largest values:9
smallest values:-10

largest values:6
smallest values:2

largest values:5
smallest values:-100

largest values:-2
smallest values:-45
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int col = 0; col < data[0].length; col++) { 

    int large = data[0][col], 
        small = data[0][col];

    for (int row = 1; row < data.length; row++) {
        if (large < data[row][col]) {
            large = data[row][col];

        }
        if (small > data[row][col]) {
            small = data[row][col];
        }

    }
    System.out.print("\nlargest values:" + large);
    System.out.print("smallest values:" +small);
}
```

Just chance your looping statement with this will give you the desired output.

Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Declare those outside the loop:

```
    int large = data[row][0], 
    int small = data[row][0];
```

and initialise them simply to the first element:

```
    int large = data[0][0], 
    int small = data[0][0];
```